# BXSlider: Getting it to Vertically Scroll to the Next Slide with mouse

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using BxSlider and I'm trying to get it to vertically scroll from one slide to the other.  I have gone through the examples and the only thing that I have found is that it lets you scroll within the same slide, but not to the next. I'm basically trying to figure out how to scroll through the slides similar to: http://www.newjumoconcept.com/ or http://www.hugeinc.com/

Here is my javascript

```
$('#content').bxSlider({
    auto: 0,
    touchEnabled: true,
    swipeThreshold: 50,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 0,
    infiniteLoop: !1,
    preloadImages: "all",
    responsive: !0,
    pagerCustom: "#pager",
    mode: "vertical",
    controls: false
  });
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jz78whwf/

How do I do this so it scrolls to the next slide and stops when the next slide is full screen?

Comment: @cr0ss why was this edited? did I do anything incorrectly?

Comment: you had a typo. Nothing special. I tried helping you but got no where, sry.

Answer (score 0):

Using: http://brandonaaron.github.io/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js

HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/160x189&text=1" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/160x189&text=1" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/160x189&text=1" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
var slider = $("ul#bxslider").bxSlider();

  $('ul#bxslider').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (delta > 0) {
      slider.goToPrevSlide();
    }
    if (deltaY < 0){
      slider.goToNextSlide();
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```